# How to serialize an array of Core Data objects into an array of string using RestKit?

Tags: ios, django, serialization, restkit

I am currently using RestKit version 0.20.3 in my iOS project to communicate with my backend web service.

In some cases, my web service returns an array of tags (django-taggit) in string format and I needed to map each tag string into a core data entity.

```
// example JSON from web service

"response" : { "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"] }


// example Core Data entities

@interface TagEntity : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *tagName;

@end
```

From the below discussion, I found a way to map an array of tag strings into core data objects.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restkit/54eZFQIjl7c

```
tagEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"TagEntity" inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
[tagEntityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping mappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"tagName"]]
tagEntityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"tagName"];
[resultEntityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"tags" toKeyPath:@"tags"withMapping:tagEntityMapping]];
```

Now, I am looking for a way to post an array of tag strings from Core Data objects to web service.

In other words, given that I have an array of TagEntity Core Data objects, I wish to send an array of [TagEntity tagName]

To achieve this, I used [resultEntityMapping inverseMapping] as a request mapping, but as result, I get

```
"request" : { "tags": [{"tag1": {}}, {"tag2": {}}, {"tag3": {}}] }
```

while what I really wish to get is

```
"request" : { "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"] }
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you set the serialisation type to JSON?

Comment: Yes I have. I have numerous features that are already working, including JSON response mapping / request serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have an array of `TagEntity` instances then you can get the array of strings with:

```
NSArray *tagStrings = [tags valueForKey:@"tagName"];
```

Once you have that you can pass the array to RestKit (wrapped into an `NSDictionary` based on your sample JSON) or use `NSJSONSerialization` directly and use the underlying AFNetworking provided API to send the JSON.

Comment: I understand that you can generate an array of tagName attributes from an array of TagEntity instances using valueForKey:. I also got that you can use NSJSONSerialization to serialize an array of tag strings without having to use RestKit. However, I already have other related attributes and entities configured so that they use RestKit to map and serialize JSON. And I would like to know whether it's possible to serialize tagStrings into JSON using RestKit. As I said before, I was able to map an array of string tags into tag entities and I am looking for a way to do the reverse. Thanks!

Comment: You could add a method onto your result entity which returns an array of strings (instead of using the array of tag entities).

Comment: Instead of using the inverse of the response mapping, I followed this method and it worked. Thanks! By the way, I wonder whether this is a RestKit bug.. shouldn't inverse mapping provide the same result?

Comment: In general, I would say yes, it should be possible for the inverse to work.